# Plug to access kernel RNG

Tags: snap

I'm looking at the list of interfaces [1] for the plug to mention if I want to access the kernel random devices (i.e. /dev/{,u}random) and I'm not finding anything that looks right. How do I read those devices from a snap?

[1] http://snapcraft.io/docs/reference/interfaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access to those devices is included in the default profile (no plugs needed). To verify this, try the following:

```
$ sudo snap install hello-world
$ apparmor_parser -p /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.hello-world.env  | grep "/dev/.\?random"
  /dev/random                    r,
  /dev/urandom                   r,
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The problem, I now realize, is that botan tries to open /dev/urandom for read-write, which, as can be seen in your answer, will be rejected by AppArmor. I didn't realize that, and assumed that there was some plug I needed.